# How to avoid last line of chapter stretching to new page in latex

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters

I am writing a tex document using `\documentclass{book}`. It is consisting of several chapters, and I am using below code to make the new chapter start on the same page:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\chapter
{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
{\par}% Inserting a \par here!
{}{}
\makeatother
```

Now I am facing another issue (as seen in attached screenshot below). As we can see, the last line of chapter (on page 2) stretches to new page even though there is sufficient space available. Is there a way to avoid this, so that the chapter 1 with word "reverence" (the last word) ends on the same page ?

[image]

Comment: Put `\looseness=-1` before a longish paragraph of that chapter on the page before the new chapter begins. `\looseness` will tell TeX to try to stretch the next/current paragraph by a given amount of lines (`-1` resulting in shortening it by one line of output).

Comment: You can see the `nowidow` package, since this is a problem of widow lines.

Comment: @Skillmon : That didn't help, using `\looseness=-1` didn't make any difference. Is there any other way ? Any idea why does it tends to stretch even though there is so much blank space on the same page ? Also the same behaviour is seen at multiple places, so is there any global setting which can help prevent this stretch in all the chapters of the book ?

Comment: @Bernard : can you please let me know how usage of `nowidow` package can help solve this problem

Comment: It breaks the last paragraph at the bottom of page, if necessary, so that the end of the paragraph on the following page has a prescribed number of lines (usually two or three). Isn't it what you want?

Comment: @Bernard : can you please let me know the exact code to achieve that ?

Comment: Could you post the preamble you use (document class and packages related to the layout)? It might be important for a code that  works.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{book}%openany makes chap start on each new page

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background} %{} removes draft from all pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}  %to use titleformat for editing chapter title
\usepackage{etoolbox}  %to start a new chapter on the same page

\setmainfont{Constantia}


\begin{document}`

Comment: @Bernard : Not sure if its clear here. If possible, please let me know the code to use `nowidow`. Meanwhile looking at how to format the preamble message above.

Comment: It's fine. I'll make an example on this basis.

Comment: Which code do you use to prevent chapters for starting a new page?

Comment: Try putting `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` (or `2\baselineskip`) on the page where you want to add an additional line of print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a small `\penalty` after `\par` in your replacement you should get what you want:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\chapter
{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
{\par\penalty100}% Inserting a \par here and allowing page breaks!
{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments} % only needed for the dummy text of `\blindduck`

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\blindduck[1-3]
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\blindduck
\end{document}
```

Page 2 without the penalty:

[image]

Page 2 with the penalty:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code demo for the `nowidow` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}%openany makes chap start on each new page
 \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[contents={}]{background} %{} removes draft from all pages
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage{titlesec} %to use titleformat for editing chapter title
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\LARGE\bfseries}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\,\Roman{chapter}}{0.5em}{}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}%Constantia
   \usepackage{etoolbox} %to start a new chapter on the same page
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[defaultlines=2]{nowidow}

   \begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}

She stood silent for a minute, thinking: then she suddenly began again.
‘Then it really HAS happened, after all! And now, who am I? I WILL
remember, if I can! I’m determined to do it!’ But being determined
didn’t help much, and all she could say, after a great deal of puzzling,
was, ‘L, I KNOW it begins with L!’

Just then a Fawn came wandering by: it looked at Alice with its large
gentle eyes, but didn’t seem at all frightened. ‘Here then! Here then!’
Alice said, as she held out her hand and tried to stroke it; but it only
started back a little, and then stood looking at her again.

‘What do you call yourself?’ the Fawn said at last. Such a soft sweet
voice it had!

‘I wish I knew!’ thought poor Alice. She answered, rather sadly,
‘Nothing, just now.’

‘Think again,’ it said: ‘that won’t do.’

Alice thought, but nothing came of it. ‘Please, would you tell me
what YOU call yourself?’ she said timidly. ‘I think that might help a
little.’

‘I’ll tell you, if you’ll move a little further on,’ the Fawn said. ‘I
can’t remember here.’

So they walked on together though the wood, Alice with her arms clasped
lovingly round the soft neck of the Fawn, till they came out into
another open field, and here the Fawn gave a sudden bound into the air,
and shook itself free from Alice’s arms. ‘I’m a Fawn!’ it cried out in a
voice of delight, ‘and, dear me! you’re a human child!’ A sudden look of
alarm came into its beautiful brown eyes, and in another moment it had
darted away at full speed.

Alice stood looking after it, almost ready to cry with vexation at
having lost her dear little fellow-traveller so suddenly. ‘However, I
know my name now.’ she said, ‘that’s SOME comfort. Alice--Alice--I won’t
forget it again. And now, which of these finger-posts ought I to follow,
I wonder?’

It was not a very difficult question to answer, as there was only one
road through the wood, and the two finger-posts both pointed along it.
‘I’ll settle it,’ Alice said to herself, ‘when the road divides and they
point different ways.’

But this did not seem likely to happen. She went on and on, a long way,
but wherever the road divided there were sure to be two finger-posts
pointing the same way, one marked ‘TO TWEEDLEDUM’S HOUSE’ and the other
‘TO THE HOUSE OF TWEEDLEDEE.’

‘I do believe,’ said Alice at last, ‘that they live in the same house! I
wonder I never thought of that before--But I can’t stay there long. I’ll
just call and say “how d’you do?” and ask them the way out of the wood.
If I could only get to the Eighth Square before it gets dark!’ So she
wandered on, talking to herself as she went, till, on turning a sharp
corner, she came upon two fat little men, so suddenly that she could not
help starting back, but in another moment she recovered herself, feeling
sure that they must be.
%
\nowidow

\chapter{ Tweedledum And Tweedledee}

They were standing under a tree, each with an arm round the other’s
neck, and Alice knew which was which in a moment, because one of them
had ‘DUM’ embroidered on his collar, and the other ‘DEE.’ ‘I suppose
they’ve each got “TWEEDLE” round at the back of the collar,’ she said to
herself.

They stood so still that she quite forgot they were alive, and she was
just looking round to see if the word “TWEEDLE” was written at the back
of each collar, when she was startled by a voice coming from the one
marked ‘DUM.’

‘If you think we’re wax-works,’ he said, ‘you ought to pay, you know.
Wax-works weren’t made to be looked at for nothing, nohow!’

‘Contrariwise,’ added the one marked ‘DEE,’ ‘if you think we’re alive,
you ought to speak.’

‘I’m sure I’m very sorry,’ was all Alice could say; for the words of the
old song kept ringing through her head like the ticking of a clock, and
she could hardly help saying them out loud:--

They were standing under a tree, each with an arm round the other’s
neck, and Alice knew which was which in a moment, because one of them
had ‘DUM’ embroidered on his collar, and the other ‘DEE.’ ‘I suppose
they’ve each got “TWEEDLE” round at the back of the collar,’ she said to
herself.

They stood so still that she quite forgot they were alive, and she was
just looking round to see if the word “TWEEDLE” was written at the back
of each collar, when she was startled by a voice coming from the one
marked ‘DUM.’

‘If you think we’re wax-works,’ he said, ‘you ought to pay, you know.
Wax-works weren’t made to be looked at for nothing, nohow!’

‘Contrariwise,’ added the one marked ‘DEE,’ ‘if you think we’re alive,
you ought to speak.’

‘I’m sure I’m very sorry,’ was all Alice could say; for the words of the
old song kept ringing through her head like the ticking of a clock, and
she could hardly help saying them out loud:--

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `\enlargethispage`

```
% ...
some text.
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
more text
% ...
```

will enable two more lines to be printed on the current page.

Comment: This won't fix the issue, the issue lies within the way he suppresses a new page for chapters, which leaves no break point between the last paragraph and the new heading.